# Does margin-at-rules work in Chrome? Why neither @page @top-center nor @bottom-right work here?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing, print-css

I have the below simple html code. I'm studying https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/.

Why the `@top-center` and `@bottom-right` doesn't show in my print preview on Chrome browser?

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      @page {
        size: A4
      }

      @page {
        @top-center {
          margin: 10pt 0 30pt 0;
          border-top: .25pt solid #666;
          content: "My book";
          font-size: 9pt;
          color: #333;
        }
      }

      @page {
        @bottom-right {
          content: "Page "counter(page) " of "counter(pages);
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body style="padding: 1.5cm">
    Hello world!
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the print preview:

[image]

Comment: I have exactly the same question! Does not work according to what is described in the documentation.

Comment: The author of the article acknowledges that this particular aspect of CSS is poorly supported, and they were using it in conjunction with a proprietary HTML-to-PDF library. To be fair to the author, it quite clearly states at the start of the article that she "will take a look at the CSS modules that have been created not for use in web browsers, but to deal with printed and paged media" i.e. no expectation it will work in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN: "Warning: The margin at-rules **have not been implemented by any user agent** (updated: August 2023)."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page#margin_at-rules

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in the W3C document [CSS Paged Media Module Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/) implementation of these selectors still appears to be at the working draft stage, so there's no expectation that this will currently be supported by browsers and the browser developers have evidently chosen not to add provisional support for it yet.